# PHPmailer google oAuth authentication failure

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, phpmailer, gmail-api, google-oauth

trying to send notification mails from my web site to myself using google smtp with phpmailer and I got to a point where I have a refresh token.

when I try to test the mail I get the following debug Error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP h6sm35172248paf.23 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:569:78a5:aa00:8d54:17b8:c04b:1f31]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:569:78a5:aa00:8d54:17b8:c04b:1f31]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1qYWNvYi5iYWxhYmFub3ZAZ21haWwuY29tAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHlhMjkuQ2pIY0FneVhWcjlvdWVSUjRYN3o1aFhvYVFrRHROTDRONEwyd21DekpfTS1FWnpESWRQSHFlZlZTSEJTa3gwLXJDZ0oBAQ==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 h6sm35172248paf.23 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 h6sm35172248paf.23 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
string 'SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting' (length=82)
```

so I tried everything and I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Did you follow the links in the error message? Dif you follow the guide in the PHPMailer wiki? PHPMailer 6.0 will be released soon, with much improved XOAUTH2 support.

Comment: Iv'e did, What I dont understand is how I get CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted, when I use Oauth2?

Comment: Based from this [forum](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1846425/error-535-with-gmail-smtp-username-and-password-not-accepted/p1), you need to set up your personal e-mail as a "send mail as" account in Gmail settings. It does not need to be an alias. Set it as the default "send mail as" account if you want to send mail as your own domain account.